# Creat Static Library in Qt5 and use it

Tags: qt, qt5

I am trying to make a library for my project. (Qt5 , Qt Creator, VS2010 compiler)

I started with a minimal test sample to check how its working.

1-I have made a library that contain a Class with a method

2-I compile it and get Dll and Lib files

3- In main aplication i add this lib and its path to .pro and tested library successfully.

Now, i want to get rid of DLL and use lib file as an static library.

So i added this line to my library .pro file

```
CONFIG+=staticlib
```

Now, i get lib file after compile, but i can not use it in my project and i get Unresolved external symbols… errors

when i remove CONFIG+=staticlib , it works again! but its not static.

these are the lines i added to .pro file of main project to load/link library

```
INCLUDEPATH +="G:/TestLib/testLib"
LIBS +=-l"G:/Build/debug/testLib"
```

So the question is : is it possible to have my own static library in Qt (none-commercial license)?

If yes, what is wrong with my approach ?

shoud i change something in LIBS+=... to specify its a static library?

I have read [This Article](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application/) and it seems nothing is wrong with my code.

Any help please?

**EDIT : Problem solved**

The problem was that we don’t need Q_DECL_EXPORT and Q_DECL_IMPORT for static libraries!
which is not mentioned in that sketchy illusory article explicitly.

Comment: Maybe you should add your solution as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved

The problem was that we don’t need `Q_DECL_EXPORT` and `Q_DECL_IMPORT` for static libraries! which is not mentioned in that sketchy illusory article explicitly.

`Q_DECL_EXPORT` and `Q_DECL_IMPORT` are necessary for dynamic libraries.